# Adding react-multi-date-picker render={<InputIcon />} will cause a browser warning

Tags: reactjs, next.js

[image: is warning]

there is no function with that name in the code..

I added the icon as the documentation suggests, but I got a warning

next-dev.js:20 Warning: React does not recognize the `handleValueChange` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `handlevaluechange` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

```js
import DatePicker, { DateObject } from "react-multi-date-picker";
import InputIcon from "react-multi-date-picker/components/input_icon";


const AddVacation: React.FC<{}> = ({}) => {

return (
  <DatePicker
    value={isDatePickerValues}
    onChange={setDatePickerValues}
    range
    rangeHover
    format={"DD.MM.YYYY"}
    render={<InputIcon />}
  />
);

};
```

Comment: There is an open github [issue](https://github.com/shahabyazdi/react-multi-date-picker/issues/208) in the [react-multi-date-picker](https://github.com/shahabyazdi/react-multi-date-picker) repo.

Answer (score 1):

The warning message indicates that there is a prop named `handleValueChange` being passed to a DOM element, but React doesn't recognize this prop as a valid attribute for the element.

React allows you to pass custom props to your components, but when it comes to standard HTML elements (e.g., `<div>`, `<input>`, etc.), you need to ensure that you're only passing valid HTML attributes as props. If you pass custom props to a DOM element, React will issue a warning because it doesn't recognize those props as standard HTML attributes.

To fix this warning, you have a few options:

1. **Use Custom Components**: If `handleValueChange` is indeed a custom prop specific to your component, make sure you are passing it to a custom React component you've created, rather than a standard HTML element. Custom React components can accept any prop you define without causing warnings.

   For example, if you have a custom input component called `CustomInput`, you can use it like this:

   ```
   <CustomInput handleValueChange={someFunction} />
   ```
2. **Remove Invalid Prop**: If `handleValueChange` is not meant to be a prop for the DOM element, you should remove it from the element. The warning message suggests using lowercase for custom attributes to avoid conflicts with standard HTML attributes.

   For example, if you were using `<input>` element:

   ```
   <input handleValueChange={someFunction} />
   ```

   Change it to:

   ```
   <input />
   ```
3. **Correct the Prop Name**: If `handleValueChange` is meant to be a prop for the DOM element, but React is not recognizing it due to capitalization, you can follow the warning's suggestion and rename it to `handlevaluechange` (all lowercase).

   ```
   <input handlevaluechange={someFunction} />
   ```

It's essential to verify where the `handleValueChange` prop is being used and make sure it's appropriately handled according to the options mentioned above.

Comment: react-multi-date-picker is a lib and I don't have access to the input.. ?

Comment: If you are using the `react-multi-date-picker` library, and you don't have direct access to the input element, it means that the library abstracts away the input element and manages it internally. In such cases, you typically interact with the library through its provided components and APIs.

To use the `react-multi-date-picker` library, you should follow the documentation and examples provided by the library's maintainers.

Comment: https://shahabyazdi.github.io/react-multi-date-picker/types/  yes I follow the documentation.. I wonder if react/nextjs can be told to ignore this warning?

Comment: @NikitaŠtšigorjev did you ever figure it out' running into this same issue on lib version 4.4.1